# Red5 media server - Simple Subscriber/Connect button does not work

Tags: streaming, red5

I'm trying to test the demos provided by the Red5 media server. I'm interested more exactly in the Simple Broadcaster app.It works fine when I test it on my machine (OS Ubuntu 12.04 - Mozilla Firefox), but when I try to connect from a different machine on the local network the connect button on that machine does nothing (Windows 7 - Mozilla Firefox/Internet Explorer). I know flash player is installed and updated to the latest version.

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ports that the Red5 server uses need to be opened on your local machine for others to be able and connect to it. So basically what you need to do is open ports 5080 and 1935.

I used these commands in the terminal:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 -s 0/0 --dport 5080 -j ACCEPT
```

and

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 -s 0/0 --dport 1935 -j ACCEPT
```